# What does this constant definition mean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What does this assignment mean?

```
const { data: scoreData } = useMostRecentScore(studentId, loginId)
```

Comment: Same thing it would in JavaScript, there's no type information in what you've shown.

Comment: It means `scoreData` will reference the `data` property of whatever `useMostRecentScore` returns. This is [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring).

Answer (score 0):

If `useMostRecentScore` returns an object, with a `data` property, it will create a new variable called `scoreData` and assign the contents of the `data` property.